# Doctrine entity class mapping issue showing fatal error

Tags: php, codeigniter, orm, doctrine-orm

facing this type of issue. I am new in doctrine with codeigniter.

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception
>   'Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException' with message 'Class
>   "Entity\Options" is not a valid entity or mapped super class.' in
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\doctrineGit\application\libraries\Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException.php:336
>   Stack trace: #0
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\doctrineGit\application\libraries\Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver.php(89):
>   Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException::classIsNotAValidEntityOrMappedSuperClass('Entity\Options')
>    #1 D:\xampp\htdocs\doctrineGit\application\libraries\Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory.php(117):
>   Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver->loadMetadataForClass('Entity\Options',
>   Object(Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata)) #2
>    D:\xampp\htdocs\doctrineGit\application\libraries\Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\AbstractClassMetadataFactory.php(318):
>   Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory->doLoadMetadata(Object(Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata),
>   NULL, false, Array) #3
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\doctrineGit\application\libraries\Doctrine\Common\Persistenc
>   in
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\doctrineGit\application\libraries\Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException.php
>   on line 336

Here is my entityclass

```
<?php

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;


/**
 * Options
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="options")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Options
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=50, nullable=true)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var boolean
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="active", type="boolean", nullable=true)
     */
    private $active = '1';


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @return Options
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }
```

Below is my model class or repository using like this where i am going wrong

```
<?php
use models\Entity\Options;

class OptionsRepository extends CI_Model {

    public $em;

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('doctrine');
        $this->em = $this->doctrine->em;
    }

    public function getOptions() {
        $dql = "SELECT o FROM \Entity\Options o";

         $query = $this->em->createQuery($dql);

        return $query->getResult();
    }

}

?>
```

Comment: Missing namespace in your Options file?

Comment: i have use namespace like this 

namespace Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;


/**
 * Options
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="options")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Options{
} it shows this error

 'Class "Entity\Options" is not a valid entity or mapped super class.'

Comment: Neither of your posted files have a namespace line in them.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't write namespace

**your entity class**

```
 <?php namespace Entity; use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;.......?>
```

and rest of ur code....

**your model**

```
<?php namespace Entity; use models\Entity\Options;.........?>
```

nd rest of ur code.......